# PrimeFaces mobile submit not working

Tags: java, jsf, mobile, jsf-2, primefaces

i am using primfaces mobile for a very simple use case, code below

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">
    <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" contentType="text/html">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>

         <h:form id="f1" action="">
         <h:messages id="m1"/>
            <pm:field id="f3">
                <p:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" id="ol1"/>
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{search.name}"/>
            </pm:field>
            <pm:field id="f2">
                <p:outputLabel for="id" value="Id:" id="ol2"/>
                <p:inputText id="id" value="#{search.id}" />
            </pm:field>

          <p:dataList id="resultList"  value="#{search.result}" var="ctr">
    <h:outputText value="#{ctr.name}, #{ctr.id}" id="ot1"/>
</p:dataList>
 <p:commandButton value="Non-Ajax Submit" id="nonAjax" action="#{search.getResults}" ajax="false" /> 
</h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

If i remove

```
    <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" contentType="text/html">
```

all works fine. If i inculde it, the content is not submited, and the method `search.getResults` is not called.

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Edit1: Only if you are developing a mobile application only**

Have you tried declaring the mobile render kit in the `faces-config.xml` instead of on the page?

```
<application>
   <default-render-kit-id>PRIMEFACES_MOBILE</application>
</application>
```

**Edit2:**

According to documentation this should work:

```
<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />
```

which means without the `contentType`. I don't know if this could be a problem.

If you are using navigation don't forget to declare a navigation handler in your `faces-config.xml`

```
<application>
   <navigation-handler>
      org.primefaces.mobile.application.MobileNavigationHandler
   </navigation-handler>
</application>
```

Comment: Hi , my app needs to have mobile and standard interface, that's why i cannot add the default render kit in faces config.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I hope we find a solution :)